# Magnolia project archetype can not resolve vaadin dependencies

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, magnolia

I'm trying to create a Magnolia project archetype:

I'm running

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/
```

I choose

5: http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/ -> info.magnolia.maven.archetypes:magnolia-project-archetype (An archetype to create a Magnolia project (a parent pom and a webapp))

archetype version I choose 1.1.0
Define value for property 'magnolia-version': 5.0.4

When I run the maven build, the webapp build fails because it cant find some vaadin libraries

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addons:icepush:jar:0.5.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addons:cssinject:jar:2.0.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addons:gwt-graphics:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addons:ckeditor-wrapper-for-vaadin:jar:7.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addon:easyuploads:jar:7.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.vaadin.addons:refresher:jar:1.2.1.7 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] myapp (parent pom) ............................. SUCCESS [0.394s]
[INFO] myapp: webapp .................................. FAILURE [1.305s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.962s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 18 13:53:45 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myapp-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project myapp-webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.vaadin.addon:easyuploads:jar:7.0.0, org.vaadin.addons:refresher:jar:1.2.1.7, org.vaadin.addons:cssinject:jar:2.0.3, org.vaadin.addons:icepush:jar:0.5.3, org.vaadin.addons:gwt-graphics:jar:1.0.0, org.vaadin.addons:ckeditor-wrapper-for-vaadin:jar:7.8.3: Failure to find org.vaadin.addon:easyuploads:jar:7.0.0 in http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of magnolia.public has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Do I need to add some maven repository ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it by adding following repository in my pom.xml

```
<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```